# how to get the spesific word from different string in php

Tags: php, html

for getting spesific word that i will use it for search term.

if i have a random word like :

```
$str="297819 - 123C, WHITLEY ROAD";
```

that $str is got from adrress which is got from autocomplete jQuery, every address is defined into 2 part. first `297819` are "code", and `123C, WHITLEY ROAD` is the "address".

i know hot to get the "code" with this following code :

```
$b = substr($str,0,strpos($str,"-")-1)
```

it will be return the "code" only.

guys can you help me how to get the address?

p.s every code and address will be disperated by `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code and address separate by `-` so you can split it Using  [**`explode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)  as

```
$str="297819 - 123C, WHITLEY ROAD";
$data=explode("-",trim($str));// split string with -
echo $code=trim($data[0]);// get code 
echo $address=trim($data[1]);// get address
```

And use `trim()` to remove unnecessary space

Comment: is that will be work if the length and name of the code and address are different?

Comment: Probably  need to add trim ()

Comment: is there any way to split that code and address? because if i input a wrong code, the suggestion will not show up, than if i submit it. it have an error with >undifined ofsset 1